# The Python assignment operator, function definitions, and variable definitions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, assignment-operator

Well... I was having a terrible time getting part of my code working, but I rearranged things and it suddenly started working correctly.  Not sure what I did to be honest, so I guess that will be the subject of this question.  I'm building a simple text-based card game that uses decks uploaded from two .txt files.  It's aimed at Magic: the Gathering, but would probably work with others if people got creative with it.  To provide a rough overview, here is how things are arranged:

```
import random

def shuffle(board1):

def game():
    #board=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    #performs most of the actions relating to the game
    board[0]=20
    board[10]=20


def gameboard(board2):
    #displays game board

def draw(board3, numcards, player):
    #draws cards

def upload(deckname):
    #uploads cards from file

def life(board4):
    #asks about which player the life total is changing on, by how much, etc.
    #and then does it

def maketoken(board5):
    #creates tokens, counters, etc. based on user input

def move(board5):
    #accepts user input and moves cards from zone to zone

def play(board6):
    #handles casting spells, using abilities, triggered abilities, etc.

#main body of program is below function definitions

board=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

deckname1=input("\nWhat is the name of deck 1?")
deckname2=input("\nWhat is the name of deck 2?")

deck1=upload(deckname1)
deck2=uplaod(deckname2)

board[1]=deck1
board[11]=deck2

#this is where a lot of the other variables get set
game()
```

(note: most of the code has been removed for brevity and prettiness, as my code is pretty ugly)

I have a college-level C++ background, and just recently decided to pick up ye olde keyboard for the heck of it, so the assignment operator (=) not working the way I expect is driving me CRAZY.  Therefore, I was also wondering if there was a way to get the functionality of the C++ '=' in Python, since I upload the decks from .txt files, and want to be through with the upload() function as soon as that's done (I use deck1=upload(deckname) (same for deck2). I want to use 'deck1' and 'deck2' to refill the decks after each game, but if I understand how '=' works in python, entering board[1]=deck1 means board[1] will point to the storage area of deck1 and changes to board[1] will change deck1, BUT I DON'T WANT THAT... GRRRR!!!!!!11).  I'm sure there's a solution out there somewhere since it's making me nutty, but I haven't been able to find it.  Thanks!!!

edit:  This was the error I received when things were set up this way:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\inventor487\Desktop\simplepy.py", line 444, in <module>
    game()
  File "C:\Users\inventor487\Desktop\simplepy.py", line 114, in game
    board[1]=deck1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'board' referenced before assignment
```

Summary:

1. Do I need to pass board to the game() function, even if it's set up as a global variable (or at least I thought it was)?  Everything seems to work fine when I assign it inside the game() function (commented out to show this). (edit: nevermind... I'm an idiot.)
2. Does assigning part of board to a value inside game() make it a local variable (e.g. where I have board[0]=20)? (edit: yes, it does apparently...)

Comment: You seem to be confused by *scope*, local scope (inside `game`) is different from global scope, and how Python handles the boundaries. Without more information however, there is not much we can help you with here. What was the error?

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you would show code that actually reproduces the unexpected behavior.

Comment: An for the C++ background: With lists you are working with references/pointers to objects. So when you say `a = b = c = []` all those variables refer to the same list object. There won't by any copies made when you pass lists around/assign them to variables/modify them.

Comment: For your board, use a list comprehension, like `board = [ [] for i in range(0, 22) ]`, it would make it so much easier. (**Edited**: Can't count, hopefully right #).

Comment: See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for more help on how to create good sample code for a question.

Comment: @jsalonen The real issue, and the recurring problem, is the assignment operator not working the way I expect it.  I need a way to create new variables with the data inside an existing variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, the `=` operator in Python doesn't make a copy of an object like it does in C++ for example. If you want to make a copy to store in another variable you have to be explicit about it.

```
board[1] = deck1[:]  # the slicing operator copies a subset or the whole list
```

A more general method is to use the [`copy` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

```
import copy
board[1] = copy.copy(deck1)
board[1] = copy.deepcopy(deck1)
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: a class solves all of this very easily, and much more cleanly.  Having a separate variable for each zone, etc. makes everything a lot smoother.  Thanks for the help, though guys.  Much appreciated.